# How to use 'where' on column with comma separated values in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

I am using php with laravel framework. I want to get rows from table that contains user id. Problem here is that user id is integer value and column(author) contain more than one comma separated integer values. Here is example.

```
DB::table('stories')->where('author','4')->get();
```

author column have values : row 1: 2,4,5 | row 2: 1,3,14 | row 3 : 4,5
and I will get row 1 and 3. So, Please help me to get right rows.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `whereRaw` like as

```
DB::table('stories')->whereRaw("find_in_set('4',author)")->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

First convert your `string` to `array` using

```
$row = "2,4,5";
$idsArr = explode(',',$row);  
DB::table('stories')->whereIn('author',$idsArr)->get();
```

Comment: Why to convert string into array if you can simply use `find_in_set`

Comment: @uchicha you are right..but different human has different mind and different mind has different way to logic... :)