# Laravel multiple category

Tags: laravel, categories

I have a category in database with value "1,2,3,4"

How to get content where category is 4

```php
$query->whereIn('category_id', 4);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'where' on column with comma separated values in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493588/how-to-use-where-on-column-with-comma-separated-values-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.

If you only need one, just use where to select specific id

```
$query->where('category_id', 4)->get();
```

For selecting multiple, use whereIn :

```
$query->whereIn('category_id', [1, 2, 3])
               ->get();
```

source:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries